# How to change this formula for python? Newbie to coding, any help is appreciated

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

Hi I have currently obtained this code from online. It currently gets the url and company information for the following tickers. Is there any way to update this code to instead to show the sector and industry information in replacement of the url and company information? Newbie to coding, so would appreciate any help :)

Code Below:

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup 
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import re
import urllib.request 
import pandas as pd
import requests

symbols = ['SBUX', 'MET', 'CAT', 'JNJ', 'ORCL']


headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

mySymbols = {}

for s in symbols:
    vals = {}
    url = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/profile?p={}".format(s,s))
    webpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(webpage.content) 

    title = soup.find("title")
    tmp = title.get_text()
    rxTitle = re.compile(r'\(.*$')
    coName = rxTitle.sub("", tmp)


for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        try:
            if link['target'] and "" == link['title']:
                m = re.search('yahoo', link['href'], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                if None == m:

                    url = link['href']
                    webpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(webpage.content) 

                    vals = {"company":coName, "url":link['href']} 
                    print (s, vals)
                    mySymbols[s] = vals
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Your code indentation as it is shown is inconsistent. I'm not certain of what it should be so I can't attempt to edit it, but it would help if you could.

Comment: Hey. I will edit it right now. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at one of those pages I see the Sector is in a span with 'class'='Fw(600)' and  'data-reactid'=21 and the industry with data-reactid=25, so you could use

```
sector = soup.find('span', {'class':'Fw(600)','data-reactid': '21'})
print(sector.next)
industry = soup.find('span', {'class':'Fw(600)','data-reactid': '25'})
print(industry.next)
```

The sector.next gets the stuff within the span instead of returning the entire thing.

A better approach that looks for the 'Sector' and 'Industry' spans and returns the subsequent span is fully coded below:

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_tags(url):
    webpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(webpage.content)
    title = soup.find("title")
    results = {}
    tmp = title.get_text()
    results['title'] = tmp
    spans = soup.findAll('span')
    for i in range(len(spans)):
        if spans[i] and spans[i].text == 'Sector':
            sector = spans[i+1].text
            results['Sector'] = sector
        if spans[i] and spans[i].text == 'Industry':
            industry = spans[i+1].text
            results['Industry'] = industry
    return results

headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
symbols = ['SBUX', 'MET', 'CAT', 'JNJ', 'ORCL']
for s in symbols:
    url = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/profile?p={}".format(s,s))
    results = get_tags(url)
    print(results)
```

Comment: Hey, I would appreciate if you can clarify how i can use it. Such as for example what aspects in my case should i change? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Much appreciated !

Comment: Another question, how would I change the results to show as a dataframe? Thanks again